# How to avoid two loops here in python

Tags: python, loops

Here is my problem: I have a dict in python such as:

```
a = {1:[2, 3], 2:[1]}
```

I would like to output:

```
1, 2
1, 3
2, 1
```

what I am doing is

```
for i in a:
    for j in a[i]:
        print i, j
```

so is there any easier way to do that avoiding two loops here or it is the easiest way already?

Comment: What you have is probably as clear as it gets. The only issue is that it doesn't produce the commas in the output, but that's trivial to fix.

Comment: It's not getting any simpler from the loops point of view, on the other hand, I'd rather write `for i, vals in a.iteritems(): for j in vals...`

Comment: You might want to switch to `for i in sorted(a):` -- right now your code doesn't necessarily give the results in increasing order of `i`.  That may not matter, though.

Comment: @DSM: Wow. I just thought "What? Sorting a dictionary?", then I tried it, and now I've learned that `sorted(mydict)` gives me a sorted list of `mydict`'s keys. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @TimPietzcker That's because the dictionary iterator returns the keys.
i.e it is equivalent to : `sorted(iter(mydict))`.

Answer (score 3):

The code you have is about as good as it gets. One minor improvement might be iterating over the dictionary's items in the outer loop, rather than doing indexing:

```
for i, lst in a.items() # use a.iteritems() in Python 2
    for j in lst:
        print("{}, {}".format(i, j))
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of alternatives using list comprehensions, if you want to avoid explicit for loops.

**# 1 method**

```
# Python2.7
for key, value in a.iteritems():    # Use a.items() for python 3
    print "\n".join(["%d, %d" % (key, val) for val in value])
```

**# 2 method** - A more fancy way with list comprehensions

```
print "\n".join(["\n".join(["%d, %d" % (key, val) for val in value]) for key, value in a.iteritems()])
```

Both will output

```
1, 2
1, 3
2, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember in Python, `Readability counts.`, so ideally @Blckknght's solution is what you should look forward, but just looking at your problem, technically as a POC, that you can rewrite your expression as a single loop, here is a solution.

But caveat, if you wan;t your code to be Readable, remember `Explicit is better than implicit.`

```
>>> def foo():
    return '\n'.join('{},{}'.format(*e) for e in chain(*(izip(cycle([k]),v) for k,v in a.items())))

>>> def bar():
    return '\n'.join("{},{}".format(i,j) for i in a for j in a[i])

>>> cProfile.run("foo()")
         20 function calls in 0.000 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <pyshell#240>:1(foo)
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <pyshell#240>:2(<genexpr>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
       10    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'format' of 'str' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'items' of 'dict' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}


>>> cProfile.run("bar()")
         25 function calls in 0.000 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <pyshell#242>:1(bar)
       11    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <pyshell#242>:2(<genexpr>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
       10    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'format' of 'str' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
```